# Is it possible to send data between two apps running on the one iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if it is possible to have two apps running on my ipad where one is sending data to the other with the latter updating it's information based on the data it has received from the first app. Please note I don't care too much about battery longevity or anything like that. I'm just trying to prove a concept and I'm new to iOS programming.

For example I'm wanting to make an app that runs and uses an iPads native Bluetooth LE functionality. I want to capture the RSSI signal strength (an integer value) and then send this a separate Unity app I also have running on the iPad.

Normally to do this I would use a network to send the bluetooth data to a server and read that from the Unity app. However I'm wanting to avoid this as much as possible.

So can I have two apps running on the one iPad where the first app is sending information it has received to the second.

Comment: I think there's a critical flaw in your plan. You're assuming the background app will continue to run while the foreground app is running. Even in iOS7 this isn't guaranteed. You can have long-running background tasks, and background app refreshes, but you can't have an app in the background run forever. They will get suspended and possibly terminated if other apps need the memory (Unity can be a memory hog). You should run your RSSI utility as a thread inside the Unity app. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) to pass information between apps.

Comment: However, calling the URL scheme will also open the other app. You can't send data to the other app without also opening it.

Comment: No, you can't send data without opening it. But you can get them to quickly switch back and forth, which wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: I need the first app to continually send its data to the second app whilst the second one is running. Could I get the first app to send its data as a background task? Opening the first app isn't an issue. It's getting the data from the first to the second.

Comment: That may work, combined with URL schemes. Give it a go and let us know :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve this with [iOS pasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Pasteboard.html) :

> A pasteboard is a secure and standardized mechanism for the exchange
>   of data within or between applications. Many operations depend on the
>   pasteboard, notable copy-cut-paste. [...] But you can also use
>   pasteboards in other situations where sharing data between
>   applications is desirable.

Comment: Would the paste board be able to take in streaming numbers from the first app and still send those to the second whilst the second is running?

Comment: Well, if you get the first to [run in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. You'll have to figure out the compromises you want to make to convert 'streaming' data to pasteboard communicatable data though.

Answer (score 1):

Have not done myself, but you can also try using UDP.  So the receiving app will need to run in background mode and listen for certain UDP multicast group address & port.  the sending app just sends data to that UDP group IP.

Comment: Don't know if this would work but it is certainly a creative solution worth knowing about

Answer (score 0):

As I know we can't read/write the data from one app to another directly . But if you send the data to one server then access that data , display it in another app .

Comment: You can if you use iCloud and both apps shared the same identifier. They are both essentially reading/writing to shared storage.